# Wondering the Google Spreadsheet Privacy

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, privacy

I have curious about when I use a free version of Google Spreadsheet. Could Google be looking into our sheet file?  Could they take some data to analyze something from our data like a company commercial, search engine something like that?

Could you guys please give me an answer for that thing, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking if your data is private and you have not shared it with anyone then you should be the only one who has access to it.   Private user data does not show up in Google searches.

This does not say that google couldn't open your file and see whats in it.  I really doubt it as how would they know your data from the data owned by millions of other people and the cat pictures.   Analysis of data only works if the data it self has meeting to the person doing the analysis your data likely only means something to you.

Google may do some analytics as to how often some types of files are accessed and how much data is in them.  Personally i doubt that google will be looking in the actually spreadsheet.  However I dont work from google and i dont think anyone here on stack can answer this question for you 100%.

You may want to consider reading though [Google
 Privacy & Terms](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/) and [Google Privacy Policy](https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/).  These files include information about what we can expect from Google in the way of protecting our data and what they use it for if at all.

Comment: @I'-'I well i guess i cant argue with that.   The question is a bit primarily opinion based but in the light of the  Cambridge Analytics Facebook issue understandable that people would wonder about the security of their data.

Comment: Thank you for all of comment and answer did you have. I ask without bias with Google product and I also might not clear to read the Google privacy. And the one thing for this answer is not involving the Cambridge Analytics Facebook's case. Thank you for all of you guys.